# Creating a load for local development data

Tags: google-app-engine, sqlite

Is there a means of keeping a non-binary form of SQLite data that I can load into my development appserver?

I first tried to download from a staging server but have been unsuccessful - I hit an issue with OpenID(?) and it looks like it's simply not possible.

The codebase I have been given currently requires me to run `old_dev_appserver --use_sqlite .` and if I run `appcfg.py download_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --kind=SomeObject --filename=dump`, I get:

```
bulkloader-log-20131219.193925
bulkloader-progress-20131219.193925.sql3
bulkloader-results-20131219.193925.sql3
dump
```

all of which are in binary format, other than the log file. I understand the binary file is protocol-buffer encoded and so it seems that is uneditable.

Is what most people do write their own code to create dummy data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what I did was to write a handler that would create data for development purposes.

If you are creating large amounts of data, it might be a little slow to have them created by a script, so what I did was to generate data once, and then make a copy of data file which I could reuse.

For this to work, you need to specify the data file location, as [per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver), e.g:

```
--datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore
```

Comment: Are you referring to an Exporter class? And I don't need very many entities - just a reasonable selection that I can define and share amongst fellow devs.